# Dynamic Templates with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I don't know how to phrase it but here goes. I would like to create a "dynamic" store for users with preferences with a specific type of products. the word dynamic isn't pertaining to the web application but the way the application handles the user's content. to make it clear here's an example

> A user sign's up for the web application to create his/her own online store. The user choose a starting store type from different stores types available. he/she chose "sports" as his/her "template". The page then loads this "template" according to what I design it to be. This time, it would load a "sports" "template" with item fields that only pertains to sporting goods, specifications that only pertains to sporting goods, web design that are crafted to attract sporting goods buyer.

so the thing here is to load a design based on what the user likes. a "dynamic" design that is different across users. like when Store A's Sporting Goods is visited by another user. the user would see a sporting goods design. design only to attract athletes/sporting guys. And another Store B's Fashion Goods is visited by the same user. the user would see a fashion goods design, complete with all the girly stuffs i wouldn't imagine.

Different "templates" contains different fields, parts, or design depending on the type of "template" the user chose in their sign up. and can be changed at will of the users config panel/ dashboard/ settings panel.

the question is, How can I implement it in angularjs with ease and It can be scaled to add more "templates".

I would like to hear from you guys ^_^

> PS: I place the word template/s in quotes because i pertain to another thing and not to the angularjs templates/ templating engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually after re-reading your post a couple of times, there are a number of different ways to "skin this cat," you speak of.

**ng-show**
Have everything on one page. Use [sessionStorage](https://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/) to manage *who* your users are. use `ng-show` to hide/show what this specific user should see.

You'll need to verify requests each time, as a pesky person could change the values of session storage.

**routing**
route the user to a different module dependent upon your needs

**Original Answer on dynamic templates/HTML**

If I understand correctly, you want to conditionally load HTML. I think you're looking for a directive.I'm actually building a page that translates XML values that represented input types, i.e. textboxes, dropdowns, etc. into HTML from a database. Sounds like a similar concept.

Here's what got me started:
http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/

I've built / am building on top of it to a great degree. Here's an abbreviated portion of what I'm doing.

HTML:

```
  <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="item in ViewModel.caseFormData.pctrl">
        <caseformbuilder pctrl="item"></caseformbuilder>
    </div>
```

By using ng-repeat on an json object, you're basically handing this directive one json object at a time. And, then using the `scope:=` notation in the directive, you're allowing an object to be passed in by attribute, `pctrl` in my case.

AngularJS directive:

```
angular.module('yourModule').directive('caseformbuilder', function($compile) {
    var elementBuilder = (function(){
        function createTextbox(txtbox){
            return '<input id="" name="" type="text" class="" placeholder=""  />';
    }

    function createLabel(lbl){
        return '<p class="">' + lbl.text + '</p>';
    }

    function templateCreator(el){
        switch(el.type) {

            case 19:
                console.log('type is 19');
                return createLabel(el);
        }
    }

    return {
        createElement: function(jsonElement){
            return templateCreator(jsonElement);
        },
    };

})();

var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.html(elementBuilder.createElement(scope.pctrl));
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
}

return {
    restrict: "E",
    link: linker,
    scope: {
        pctrl:'='
    }
};
```

});

I hope this gets you started and pointed in the right direction!

Comment: Thank you sir for taking time to answer my question. I did found your work very informative and thus would assure me that I would be on the right track with it.